# Подскажите компонент для выбора цвета

Tags: color, javascript, html

Подскажите компонент для выбора цвета: желательно как в word - дается стандартная палитра и уж если мало, то доп выбор.

Нужна палитра cmyk.

Comment: конкретное ничего не подскажу, но гугли в сторону **jquery color picker**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Их достаточно много. Выбирайте на любой вкус: [ColorPicker](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker).